# How to call a Python class method on another method from the same class instance

Tags: python

I am building a class to hold data for customer's reports.  The class will contain information about the customer as well as data in the form or "rows".  I will also need to add and remove data rows from the class.

*Example Class returning data rows, with add and delete methods*

```
class Reports:
     
    def data_row(self):
          ...
          return data
    
    def add(self, data):
        "add data row to instance"
    
    def del(self, num):
        "delete data row from instance"
```

My thought was that in the code it would be cleanest to add and remove data by being able to call the class like this:

```
report_1 = Reports()

report_1.data_row.add('red apples are great') 
report_1.data_row.add('black trucks are cool')

print(report_1.data_row())
```

> red apples are great
>
> black trucks are cool

```
report_1.data_row.del(1)

print(report_1.data_row())
```

> black trucks are cool

How can I structure the class to be able to call a method that acts on another method like the example above?  Is this good python code?

Comment: `report_1.data_row` would need to be *an object* that implements those methods you want to call on it. And it also needs to implement `__call__` so you can do `report_1.data_row()`. So it can't be a *method* on another object, it needs to be a *class* itself which you assign to `report_1.data_row = YourMagicClass()`.

Comment: That seems pointlessly complicated to me. The normal way to do this, much easier to implement and much easier to understand after, is to use `report_1.add("contents")`.

Comment: I'm confused. If you say `del(1)` doesn't that delete the second entry since counting is from 0 index?

Comment: @joanis I updated example to show `report_1.add('contents')`, your suggestion is correct.

Comment: @astrochun yes, if I setup my method to start the count from 0 you are correct.

Comment: With your updated question, the class just looks like a list. Maintain a list inside the class as a member, then have `add()` and `del()` add or remove elements from that list, and `data_row()` return the whole list in its current state, possibly formatted to meet your report's requirements. I would give `data_row()` a more intuitive name, though, like `format_report()`. Give the method a name that describes what it does. To me, "data row" says it's going to return one row, not all the data.

Comment: @joanis I see what you are saying, I will give it some thought.  I believe that Reddy's answer below achieves what I am try to accomplish.  I need to think about which is the better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that behaviour doesn't make sense in terms of Single responsibility
if

In order to accomplish:

```
report_1 = Reports()

report_1.data_row.add() = "red apples are great"  
report_1.data_row.add() = "black trucks are cool"
print(report_1.data_row)
```

```py
class DataRow:
    def __init__(self, data=""):
        self.data = data
    
    def add(self, data_to_add):
        self.data = self.data + data_to_add  

    def del(self, num):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        # this will be printed when you call print(reports.data_row) no need to call data_row as a method 

class Reports:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_row = DataRow()
```

you can't expect report_1.data_row have 2 different behaviour, 1 as method and one as an object

I suggest you to review OOP and SOLID concepts, also one thing that is wrong in the question
the methods that you showed are not `class methods` those are instance methods (check this)[https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/]

Comment: `.add() = "..."`…?!

Comment: @reddy I think that answers my question.  Essentially I need to structure as 2 classes, one class that will store the data, **Reports**.  Every _data row_ in the **Reports** class will be an instance of the **DataRow** class.  Did I get concept correct?